# MySql update with running totals

Tags: mysql

I have a MySql transaction table 'tBilling'.  The user has the ability to edit or insert a row for a customer.

What I need to do is update the Balance for that row, and every transaction with a date greater than or equal the date of the new/modified transaction

```
PK   Cust  TDate           Amt        Balance
==============================================
'1', '22', '2021-03-27',  '400.25',  '400.25'
'2', '31', '2021-04-03',  '111.00',  '111.00'
'3', '31', '2021-04-04',  '222.00',  '333.00'
'4', '31', '2021-04-05',  '112.00',  '445.00'
'5', '31', '2021-04-06', '1234.10', '1679.10'
'6', '22', '2021-04-04',  '112.23',  '200.00'
```

I thought I had it with this... but it doesn't get the previous Balance.  For example, if I edit row 3, the new Balance will be equal to the Amt (222.00), not the Amt + previous balance.

```
set @csum := 0;
update tBilling
set Balance = (@csum := @csum + Amt)
where Cust = 31 and TDate >= '2021-04-04'
order by TDate;
```

I experimented with the window functions but didn't make progress.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're taking the wrong approach. Don't maintain changing data in the tables. Calculate it when it's needed: set up a view of it's needed regularly.

Comment: The problem is, the user can select what time frame to view, and also, there may be a LOT of transactions.